# What does the following Shloka mean and can someone find me a source of this Shloka?

Tags: identification-request, translation-request, sanskrit

> [tarti shokmatmavit brahmosanstho mrutvameti](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iDHUO.jpg)

[image]

I am trying to search for the meaning of the shloka but I am not able to find it so far, it would be helpful if someone can find the reference, and translate this for me .

*Extremely sorry for writing this completely wrong*

Comment: Hi! Welcome to Hindusim SE. Please take a [TOUR](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/tour) of this site to get acquainted. Further, kindly visit [How does a new user get started on Hinduism SE?](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33/how-does-a-new-user-get-started-on-hinduism-se). For more info please do visit: [the HSE Help Center](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/help). Have an enriching journey!!

Comment: It's in Gujarātī (તરતિ શોકમાત્મવિતા બ્રહ્મસંસ્થો મૃતત્વમેતિ) someone who can read and understand the lang., you can show it to them